# CSS Tweak to Simple Drop Down Menus

Tags: html, css, menu

I'm using some [simple dropdown menus](http://www.handy-html.com/simple-css-dropdown-menu-updated/) I found online and I need help with a CSS / HTML tweak.

Currently they expand as you add menus.  I'm using them on an old Intranet I inherited that is 960px wide.  I they would look nicer if they were flush with a 960px wide banner above.

[The way the menus line up now](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0By_2YLvaQba0OWtKUXVwZW01MTg/edit?usp=sharing)

Here is my CSS.

```
div.wrapper {
width : 960px ;
margin-left : auto ;
margin-right : auto ;
}
ul#nav {margin: 0 0 0 0;}
ul.drop a { display:block; color: #fff; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 14px; text-decoration: none;}
ul.drop, ul.drop li, ul.drop ul { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 14px; list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 1px solid #fff; background: #B0CD2C; color: #fff;}
ul.drop { position: relative; z-index: 597; float: left; }
ul.drop li { float: left; line-height: 1.3em; vertical-align: middle; zoom: 1; padding: 7px 11px; }
ul.drop li.hover, ul.drop li:hover { position: relative; z-index: 599; cursor: default; background: #20413A; }
ul.drop ul { visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0; z-index: 598; width: 195px; background: #555; border: 1px solid #fff; }
ul.drop ul li { float: none; }
ul.drop ul ul { top: -2px; left: 100%; }
ul.drop li:hover > ul { visibility: visible }

<div align="center">
<div class="wrapper"><img alt="Banner Graphic" height="152" src="/Web_Changes/banner.jpg" width="960" />
</div>
<!--Begin Menus-->  

<ul id="nav" class="drop">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li>About Us
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Staff</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">George Orsmond</a>
        <ul>
          <li>Web Design</li>
          <li>Graphic Design</li>
          <li>HTML</li>
          <li>CSS</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Dave Macleod</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
      <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Services
    <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Graphic Design</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Logo Design</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Products
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Templates</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Stock Images</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Category 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Category 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Category 5</a></li>
    </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Featured</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Top Rated</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
  <li>Contact Us
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Form</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">How to get here</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">View the map</a></li>
   </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Will someone help me tweak these to be flush on both sides to 960px?

Comment: Not possible to apply css on the image that you have posted :). Please post markup too, possibly a fiddle.

Comment: I put the link to the menus I'm using above in the first sentence.  Sorry about that.  I am using these things verbatim with an exception to the margins and colors.

Comment: you could give us a link to Microsoft itself, but that doesn't mean we can see / fix the code. Please provide the HTML for banner and menu, and the CSS for the banner as well.

Comment: do you want your menus to be the same width as banner (960px)?

Comment: Imho, dropdown menus are easier to code by hand then getting them from somewhere... That way it's easier to see what bugs your code.

Comment: Yes. I would like to wrap if the world was perfect if they get wider than 960px.  I like the padding dividing the cells now as a minimum, but I suppose the padding would just get larger to accommodate the missing width.  I'm not sure how this is done in CSS?

Comment: That html if very wrong. Assuming thats your actual html, id suggest fixing that before trying to polish a poo.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<style>
div.wrapper {
    width : 960px;
    margin-left : auto;
    margin-right : auto;
}
ul#nav {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
ul.drop a {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.drop, ul.drop li, ul.drop ul {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 14px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    background: #B0CD2C;
    color: #fff;
}
ul.drop {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 597;
    float: left;

}
ul.drop li {
    float: left;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    zoom: 1;
    padding: 7px 11px;
}
ul.drop li.hover, ul.drop li:hover {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 599;
    cursor: default;
    background: #20413A;
}
ul.drop ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 598;
    width: 195px;
    background: #555;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
ul.drop ul li {
    float: none;
}
ul.drop ul ul {
    top: -2px;
    left: 100%;
}
ul.drop li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">

  <div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="drop" id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li>About Us
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Staff</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">George Orsmond</a>
              <ul>
                <li>Web Design</li>
                <li>Graphic Design</li>
                <li>HTML</li>
                <li>CSS</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Dave Macleod</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Services
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Graphic Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Logo Design</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Products
      <ul>
        <li class="dir"><a href="#">Templates</a></li>
        <li class="dir"><a href="#">Stock Images</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Category 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Category 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Category 5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Featured</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Top Rated</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li>Contact Us
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Form</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">How to get here</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">View the map</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <img alt="Banner Graphic" height="152" src="/Web_Changes/banner.jpg" width="960" /> </div>
  <!--Begin Menus-->


</div>
</body>
</html>
```